# How to make onOverScrolled backwards compatible?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to update an application, and the onOverScrolled method is exactly what I need. However, my application now has a minimum api version 8, and onOverScrolled requires 9.

I've done some searching, but been unable to find any way to recreate this functionality on API Level 8. Is there something out there that would allow me to replicate this method? Any tips on recreating its functionality?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is that get the Source Code of ScrollView, and place that in your application and use it as a Custom Widget.

Or, you can just skip API v8, and just go with API v9 instead, since Gingerbread is the most prominent Android version with ICS still catching up.

However, if you decide to go with this, let me warn you about using OnOverScrolled() on the default ScrollView. Samsung has customized this functionality in their ScrollViews on the Galaxy S3, at least(I haven't checked on any other of their ICS devices, but it works on the 2.3 devices). The OnOverScrolled event will never be triggered because they are consuming the event internally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Particularly thanks for the warning about scollview on Samsung phones. I'm going to see if I can implement this functionality myself. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. A client needed us to implement a scroll view to load next item on one of our apps.. Imagine my surprise when the S3 wouldn't handle the event..